# CSS @page is not applying

Tags: wordpress, css, media-queries

I have these huge text block on pages that need to be printed, and I want to add top and bottom margin so the text is not so close to the edge of the printed page. Since these text blocks cannot be broken down with tags because they are aggregated by a rss feed crawler, I tried using @page in css but no success so far. I'm using Chrome and the printer preview. I'm using wordpress, if it matters.

Here's an image of what it looks like in PDF.
[Printed text block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2nPE.jpg)

I tried putting it in `@media screen` or `@media print`, adding `!important` and I've been searching the web for an hour now...

I added this CSS (and tried other variants) in my CSS file but it doesn't apply. All other @media print styles are working.

```
@page { 
  margin-top: 2cm;
  }
```

Any pointers would be appreciated so I can add a margin top and bottom to printed pages.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing printed elements is generally done by using `@media print`, as you already wrote. But in addition, you need a selector inside that media query. So if those text blocks have for example class `.my_class`, the CSS would be

```
@media print {
  .my_class {
    margin-top: 2cm;
  }
}
```

If the text blocks don't have any class, consider applying a class to them in HTML or in the script that generates them.

---

Addition after comment:

Did you try to *combine*  `@media print` and `@page`? Like this (I usually use it that way and it works for me):

```
@media print {
    @page  { 
        margin-top: 2cm;
    }
}
```

Comment: The text blocks are within tags with class, but they are often 2 pages long so page-breaks happen within the text blocks and I can't insert tags within them.

Comment: please note my addition